# Projection onto the Set of Circulant Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection, circulant-matrices

Defining $ \mathcal{C}_{n} $ the set of Real [Circulant Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

The orthogonal projection of a given matrix $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ onto the set is given by the following minimization problem:

$$ \arg \min_{X \in \mathcal{C}_{n} } \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X - Y \right\|}_{F}^{2} $$

Where $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{F} $ is the [Frobenius Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).

Since the set of Circulant Matrices is [Convex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) and the objective function is convex the whole problem is a convex optimization problem.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/295232/91764

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Lovely! Really nice solution there. I feel satisfied that my approach was similar to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 001

Defining the Forward Shift Matrix:

$$ \Pi = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  & 0 \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
0 &  &  &  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 &  & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

One could see that the set $ \left\{ {\Pi}^{k} \mid k \in \left\{ 0, 1, \ldots, n - 1 \right\} \right\} $ is [Orthogonal Basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis) (Can become Orthonormal with division by $ \sqrt{n} $) with respect to [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product).

Since Circulant Matrix is composed by shifting forward the first row of the matrix one could see that any Circulant Matrix $ C $ with its first row given by $ c $ can be built as following:

$$ C = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} {c}_{k} {\Pi}^{k - 1} $$

Namely, this Shift Forward matrix is the basis of Circulant Matrices.
Hence, just like we build Fourier Series Coefficients by projection onto the basis, given a Matrix $ A $ we can create its projection by:

$$ {a}_{k} = \frac{1}{n} \left \langle A, {\Pi}^{k - 1} \right \rangle, \; k \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \right\} $$

Where $ \left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle $ is the Frobenius Inner Product - $ \left \langle A, B \right \rangle = {A}^{H} B $.

Then the Circulant Matrix closest to A is given by:

$$ {P}_{\mathcal{C}^{n}} \left( A \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} {a}_{k} {\Pi}^{k - 1} $$

The funny thing is this gives me better result than my solution above even if I allow Complex Matrices (Which means something isn't right).

Comment: Related to what I showed in - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2778241/33 (Eigenvalues of Circulant Matrix).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 002

Since $ X $ is Circulant Matrix it is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) by the [DFT Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).
Hence $ X = {F}^{H} \operatorname{diag} \left( x \right) F $ where $ x $ is the Fourier Transform of the first row of $ X $.
Now, Since $ F $ is [Unitary Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and our objective function is Euclidean Distance which is invariant to multiplication by Unitary Matrix the problem can be rewritten as following:

$$ \arg \min_{X \in \mathcal{C}_{n} } \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X - Y \right\|}_{F}^{2} = \arg \min_{X \in \mathcal{C}_{n} } \frac{1}{2} {\left\| F X {F}^{H} - F Y {F}^{H} \right\|}_{F}^{2} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} } \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \operatorname{diag} \left( x \right) - F Y {F}^{H} \right\|}_{F}^{2} $$

The above is clearly minimized by $ {x}_{i} = {\left( F Y {F}^{H} \right)}_{ii} $.
Namely $ x $ is the diagonal of $ F Y {F}^{H} $.

To generate the corresponding Real Circulant Matrix one should use the same deocmposition:

$$ X = {F}^{H} \operatorname{diag} \left( x \right) F $$

In cases $ Y $ is real matrix the above will yield a real matrix as well (Up to numerical issues due to quantization).