# Prove that for every root of unity $z$ of size $n$, the vector ($1, z, z^2,..., z^{n-1}$) is an eigenvector of the circulant matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

Let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in \Bbb{C}$. Let

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{n-1} &a_n\\ a_n & a_1 & \dots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\a_2 & a_3 & \dots & a_n & a_1\end{bmatrix} $$

How can I prove that for every root of unity $z$ of size $n$, the vector ($1, z, z^2,\dots, z^{n-1}$) is an eigenvector of $A$?

I'm studying linear algebra and I encountered some difficulties with this task. I would love to get some hints or an answer for this one.

Comment: Have you tried a few simple examples?

Comment: Err, you just write it out. Like $a_2z$ is in the first row, $a_2z^2$ is in the second and the second is supposed to be $z$ times the first.

Comment: Trying for lower n (e.g. n=2) might help you a lot.

Comment: Hint: based on the first row, if it is an eigenvector, what is its eigenvalue? Using $z^n=1$, check this candidate eigenvalue also works for the other rows. (You'll work modulo $n$, so it may also help to relabel the parameters as $b_i=a_{i+1},\,0\le i\le n-1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=(1,z,\ldots,z^{n-1})$.

Begin by computing the first coordinate of $Av$. It is $\lambda=a_1+a_2z+a_3z^2+\cdots+a_nz^{n-1}$. Since the first coordinate of $v$ is 1, $\lambda$ must be the eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to $v$ if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Now compute the $i$th coordinate of $Av$ and verify that it is $\lambda z^{i-1}$ (as you want it to be). This shows that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'm not exactly sure why this question is considered of poor quality - it has a reasonable title, the details are complete and the tags are reasonable. Would you mind clarifying the issue so that I can avoid repeating my mistake?

Comment: Because it is a “solve this problem for me” type of question. The OP displayed no attempt at solving it.

Comment: You should have said that his is connected to the fact that the discrete Fourier matrix of order $n$ diagonalizes circulant matrices : see for that the very interesting answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2778241/305862)